# Finding Android source code

Tags: android, api, android-source

Are the Android APIs open source? If so, I want to see how they implemented the smoothscroll method for the ListView object (this is implemented in API level 8, but I want to build against an earlier API level). How would I go about finding this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what you want: [ListView source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/widget/ListView.java).

Comment: The smoothscroll code is actually inherited from AbsListView (http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/java/android/widget/AbsListView.java;h=fcfecb30ca70f665df7a017ac4bdbfdaeec0baa5;hb=HEAD#l2750)

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it's open source, and http://source.android.com/ has all the information on how to download and browse the source.