# Where can get the Android source code?

Tags: android

Such as when I use the ArrayAdapter class, I want to know what is be done in the class. Sometimes I want to go the source code to find answer. 
So, my question is where can get the source code ?

Comment: Search for 'android source' on google... the first result is what you want.

Comment: **Similar of [Finding Android source code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3673468/finding-android-source-code) and [Where can I browse Android source code on-line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/449763/where-can-i-browse-android-source-code-on-line)**

Answer (score 2):

http://source.android.com/source/index.html

Answer (score 2):

http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3_r1/

Answer (score 0):

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/froyo-release/core/java/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java

is the link for ArrayAdapter used in the latest Froyo release from Googles open source repository. You can use the navigation links on that page to get to the other parts of the available source code and other releases of Android.